# ng-model data is not binding for selected ng-option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options, angular-ngmodel

**HTML**

```
<select
    ng-model="selected1"
    ng-options="item.Name as item.Name for item in jobLineClassFSC"
    class="gridinputs">
</select>
<select
    ng-model="selectedJobLineTypeFSC"
    ng-options="item.Name as item.Name for item in jobLineTypeFSC">
</select>

<select
    ng-model="selectedJobLineSubTypeFSC"
    ng-options="item.Name as item.Name for item in jobLineSubTypeFSC">
```

I'm getting the result and display it properly; but the selected list is not getting bound to the ng-model and I don't know why. I implemented the same in another place in my project it's working over there. Can anyone please let me know how to do that. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: can you show your JS code please ?

Comment: Always have a `dot` in `ng-model` , you will have far less of these problems!

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be your select tags are in different scope to your controller. So the `ng-model` store selected values inside the wrong scope.

To avoid this the best practice is to use the dot notation like `model.selectedJobLineTypeFSC`:

```
<select ng-model="model.selectedJobLineTypeFSC"
        ng-options="item.Name as item.Name for item in jobLineTypeFSC"></select>
```

And in the controller check for `$scope.model.selectedJobLineTypeFSC` instead.

Comment: I tried the same as you are saying but still having same problem.

Comment: There is not enough information, please show your javascript code i.e. in controller, so we could help.